# Django: annotate a query set with the total count of a nested relation

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a situation similar to the following:

```py
class Team(models.Model):
    pass

class Player(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)

class Point(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
```

For ordering purposes (with django-tables2), I would like to annotate a QuerySet with the team's total point count, something akin to the following:

```py
Team.objects.annotate(point_count=Count('player_set__point_set')) \
            .order_by('point_count')
```

This, however, does not work. Is there a way to achieve the same?

Comment: You want to calculate total point of a team and order by them?

Comment: what is the result you are getting.

Comment: use `player__set_point__set` as parameter inside the `Count` function

Comment: @shafik that's exactly right!

Comment: @shourav: field not found. But actually, my issue is that some how the "_set" suffix was not present on the second class, for some reason that I do not comprehend. So the Count('player_set__point') worked for me.